# Conversion of HTML to PDF: tcpdf throws errors on large data

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I have a web page and I want to convert it to the PDF format. This page is PHP, so its output is dynamic. I used tcpdf, but it throws errors. It contains a large amount of data.

Comment: How did you attempt to use “tcpdf”, and what errors, specifically, did it throw?

Comment: Hi, me used tcpdf it works fine for small amount of data (eg: one div with 10 or more paragraphs) but it didn't work for large amount of data my page contains data which is the result of php execution, it contains tables divs and high charts , it throws the error large amount of data,  first argument to be array etc

Comment: Your comment answered neither of the questions asked.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend [`wkhtmlpdf`](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/), which uses WebKit to render PDFs.  Here's a PHP wrapper (can't vouch for this one specifically): http://mikehaertl.github.com/phpwkhtmltopdf/ .  I've used `exec` to generate them in the past.

Comment: i got error  proc_open() [<a href='function.proc-open'>function.proc-open</a>]: CreateProcess failed, error code - 2 in C:\wamp\www\Temple Connection\htmlpdf\WkHtmlToPdf.php on line 300   . pls help

Comment: hi N Rohler pls help me , when i used  wkhtmlpdf i got error proccess not start. i used a page with extension .php , will it proccess an error ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using fixed width in html with large amount of data then it will not generate pdf.  I would suggest you try few things .This is not a permanent solutions but Hopefully it works for you.

```
1) Use LANDSCAPE orientation if large amount of data in your page .
2) Change default page format A4 to A3
```

You can change both arrangement by using below line .

```
$pdf->AddPage('L', 'A3');
```

instead of **$pdf->AddPage();**

and

```
3) increase set_time_limit value, default it is 30. 

  for e.g set_time_limit(60);
```

Answer (score -1):

[Prince](http://www.princexml.com) converts HTML to PDF and also has a [PHP wrapper](http://www.princexml.com/download/wrappers).